# Recursively move folders within subfolders to its parent

Tags: bash, directory, subdirectory

I have a master folder (reffered to as level 0) which contains over 50 subfollders, (level 1), and those subfolders consist of lower level subfolders and files (level 2). I need to move every folder and their contents from level 2 to it's level 1 subfolder (or relatively, its parent).

To better visualize this:

```
Master folder
├ Parent Folder A
│ ├─ Subfolder A
│ │  ├─ File A
│ │  └─ File B
│ ├─ Subfolder B
│ │  ├─ File C
│ │  └─ Folder D
.
. ... more folders ...
.
└─ Parent folder 134
   ├─ Subfolder CS
   │  ├─ File AGF
   │  └─ File ARH
   ├─ File ROQ
   └─ File JGL
```

I need to move the folders within the parent folders and their files to the master folder

Objective:

```
Master folder
├─ Subfolder A
│  ├─ File A
│  ├─ File B
│  ├─ File C
│  ├─ File D
│  ├─ File E
│  └─ File F
├─ Subfolder B
│  ├─ File AZA
│  ├─ File AZB
│  ├─ File AZC
│  └─ File AZD
... and so on
```

The problem here is that there are hundreds of parent and subfolders, and they all have different names that may change. The amount of them may change aswell. I have no idea where to start. I need to do this in a bash script, and while I have found others that have done this, they have all done it within powershell.
Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: You can probably achieve this by utilising find and parsing the output through awk to create and execute the command required,

Comment: I've never used find that much before so I'm probably wrong, but wouldn't find be looking for specific file or directory names? Would wildcards somehow be able to be used for my usecase?

Comment: You can use find to look for all files and directories if required,

Comment: If a level 2 folder has a level 3 folder with a level 4 folder in it, are those to be left as intact structure, or all flattened out with only files under level 1 and no subfolders at all?

Comment: Left as intact is what I am going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you want every file under each folder to be moved out of any subfolders up to the first folder under the master.

A simplistic version of that might look like this:

```
$: find # starting test structure
.
./a
./a/a.txt
./a/e
./a/e/ae.txt
./a/f
./a/f/af.txt
./a/g
./a/g/ag.txt
./b
./b/b.txt
./b/e
./b/e/be.txt
./b/f
./b/f/bf.txt
./b/g
./b/g/bg.txt
./c
./c/c.txt
./c/e
./c/e/ce.txt
./c/f
./c/f/cf.txt
./c/g
./c/g/cg.txt
$: for f in $PWD/*/;  # for all the subdirectories in the base folder 
>  do find $f -type f | xargs -Ithis mv this "$f/"; # move all files up to that sub
>     for d in "$f"/*/; do rm -fr "$d"; done;       # and remove all lower empty subs
>  done
$: find # result
.
./a
./a/a.txt
./a/ae.txt
./a/af.txt
./a/ag.txt
./b
./b/b.txt
./b/be.txt
./b/bf.txt
./b/bg.txt
./c
./c/c.txt
./c/ce.txt
./c/cf.txt
./c/cg.txt
```

## EDIT

Moving subdirectories makes it a lot easier, I think...

```
$: for b in ./*/*/; do cp -r "$b" ./; rm -fr "$b"; done
$: find
.
./a
./a/a.txt
./b
./b/b.txt
./c
./c/c.txt
./e
./e/ae.txt
./e/be.txt
./e/ce.txt
./f
./f/af.txt
./f/bf.txt
./f/cf.txt
./g
./g/ag.txt
./g/bg.txt
./g/cg.txt
```

Note that in my test I had e, f, & g under each of a, b, & c, so the files collected into the single new level 2 directories. If there are any files with the same names in similarly named directories, you'll get whichever processes last.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I meant to move the actual subdirectories out of their parents into the master. That will probably come in handy later though.